# Does my edit of participle clause of "an action that is the result of another action" make sense?

Tags: future-tense, tense-agreement

OP:

> moments later a bomb exploded, leaving three people dead and twelve others injured

1. Can i change it into future tense of participle clause? Like

> soon, a bomb will explode, leaving three people dead and twelve others injured

2. Does it fit in with all kinds of tenses?

Comment: Yes you could say that in all tenses

Answer (score 1):

Although it is called "***Present* Participle clause**", it does not have to always reflect the action happening in *the present*.  The name comes from the **verb form** on which it's based, the *present participle* ("verb+***ing***").

When interpreting the sentence, the dependent clause (the participle clause) should be thought of in the same tense as the main clause.  The main clause, of course, can be in any grammatical tense you need it to be.

> Houses often burn, leaving families homeless.
>   The house burned, leaving the family homeless.
>   If gas ignites, the house will burn, leaving the family homeless.
>   The house has burned to the ground, leaving the family homeless.
>   Yesterday we reported that their house had burned, leaving the family homeless.

It is also possible with Continuous tenses:

> I work hard, hoping to see her again.
>   I will work hard, hoping to see her again.
>   I am working hard, hoping to see her again.
>   I've been working hard, hoping to see her again.

and so on...

Comment: by the way, Does "houses often burn,leaving families homeless" mean " while house leave families homeles , houses often burn" ?... but  i cannot get what things make house burn... leaving families homeless is actually not a reason to make a house burn ,,,,there must be something like a gas or fire..

Comment: and in you second example, can i change the order without effecting the meaning? like "hoping to see her again,i work hard"

Comment: the order does not really matter right?

Comment: "Houses often burn, leaving families homeless" = "Families are left homeless **as the result** when houses burn".  Remember, bomb exploding, leaving people dead?

Comment: "Work, hoping" example is for simultaneous actions.  = "I work as I hope".  Yes, you can change the order.

Comment: frankly， your sentence is MULTIFUNCTIONAL... " i work hard,hoping to see her again" can be either " i work hard as i hope to see her again" or "i work hard because i hope to see her again"...   it fits in with  either "an action that happens at the same time as the action in the main clause" or "a reason  for the action in the main clause"

Comment: Not really. "Hoping" is never a reason for working.  Perhaps if you said "I drove home slowly, hoping to miss Jane", there might be the "reason" connection ("I drove home slowly ***because*** I hoped to miss Jane"), but work-hope there is no such connection, or at least I didn't write it with it in mind.